# it
dresses or dressed?

Tags: word-choice, reported-speech

I know that when writing a sentence in past tense we should not use present tense in the same sentence without a proper reason. But I'm not sure which tense to use in the following sentence.

> Kristy cautioned us not to judge womanhood by the way it ***dresses or dressed***.

The sentence is in the past, so **it dressed** makes sense to me. But at the same time, the subject was giving an advice that should always be followed. Does this make **it dresses** acceptable in the sentence?

Could someone please help me decide which tense to use in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tense in reported speech does not change when a permanent or unchanging truth or habitual fact is discussed. 'The way womanhood dresses' is a habitual fact.

[Direct and indirect speech](https://www.edudose.com/english/direct-and-indirect-speech-rules/)